# PHP Combine 2 array if key value is same

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have list of arrays.

```
$array1 = array('SrNo' => 'xyzO' , 'AirlineCode' => '9E' , 'FlightNo' => '777')

$array2 = array('SrNo' => 'xyzR' , 'AirlineCode' => '6G' , 'FlightNo' => '546')

$array3 = array('SrNo' => 'abcO' , 'AirlineCode' => '5H' , 'FlightNo' => '423')

$array4 = array('SrNo' => 'abcR' , 'AirlineCode' => '2G' , 'FlightNo' => '420')
```

if **SrNo** is same for 2 array than I want to get result like below.

```
details=>[
  [1]=>[
     ['onwards']=>[
          ['SrNo' => 'xyzO' , 'AirlineCode' => '9E' , 'FlightNo' => '777'],
     ['return']=>[
          ['SrNo' => 'xyzR' , 'AirlineCode' => '6G' , 'FlightNo' => '546']
      ],

  [2]=>[
     ['onwards']=>[
          ['SrNo' => 'abcO' , 'AirlineCode' => '5H' , 'FlightNo' => '423'],
     ['return']=>[
          ['SrNo' => 'abcR' , 'AirlineCode' => '2G' , 'FlightNo' => '420']
      ]       

  ]    

]
```

last character of SrNo is **O** than it's onwards otherwise it's return.

I have tried `in_array` and `array_key` functions but I'm not getting output as I need.

Comment: Always four arrays?

Comment: Is it always so that the first array becomes the onwards one?

Comment: @Andreas not always four array. it's example. may be hundreds of possible.

Comment: @Qirel yes , first array will be onwards. SrNo. format is like this : xyzO , xyzR. here if last word is O than onwards otherwise return

Comment: if this is so please update your array SrNo in the question

Comment: It's a bit unclear what exactly you have and what is needed to be done. Is this "correct"? https://3v4l.org/q5TpR

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
// somehow we need a common entry binding all the arrays to be considered together ...
$all2=array($array1,$array2,$array3,$array4); 
// collect journeys into a hash according to their `SrNo`
foreach ($all2 as $jrn) $coll[$jrn['SrNo']][]=$jrn; 

// rearrange ...
$k=0;
foreach ($coll as $jrn) {$res[++$k]['onwards']=$jrn[0];$res[$k]['return']=$jrn[1];} 

print_r($res);
```

This results in the following output (see [here for a demo](http://rextester.com/XZF37557)):

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [onwards] => Array
                (
                    [SrNo] => xyz
                    [AirlineCode] => 9E
                    [FlightNo] => 777
                )

            [return] => Array
                (
                    [SrNo] => xyz
                    [AirlineCode] => 6G
                    [FlightNo] => 546
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [onwards] => Array
                (
                    [SrNo] => abc
                    [AirlineCode] => 5H
                    [FlightNo] => 423
                )

            [return] => Array
                (
                    [SrNo] => abc
                    [AirlineCode] => 2G
                    [FlightNo] => 420
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is not exactly requested solution. Is an alternative, easy to read and easy to manage. If the key is SrNo, ... Just store SrN0 as key, ... instead of numeric index.

```
<?php

$array1 = array('SrNo' => 'xyzO' , 'AirlineCode' => '9E' , 'FlightNo' => '777');
$array2 = array('SrNo' => 'xyzR' , 'AirlineCode' => '6G' , 'FlightNo' => '546');
$array3 = array('SrNo' => 'abcO' , 'AirlineCode' => '5H' , 'FlightNo' => '423');
$array4 = array('SrNo' => 'abcR' , 'AirlineCode' => '2G' , 'FlightNo' => '420');

$collection = [
    $array1,
    $array2,
    $array3,
    $array4,
];

$newCollection = [];

passthru('clear');

foreach ($collection as $itemKey => $itemValue) {
    $key = substr($itemValue['SrNo'], 0, 3);
    if (!isset($newCollection[$key])) {
        $newCollection[$key] = [
            'onwards' => $itemValue,
        ];
    } else {
        $newCollection[$key]['return'] = $itemValue;
    }
}

echo json_encode($newCollection, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Ths will output:

```
{
    "xyz": {
        "onwards": {
            "SrNo": "xyz",
            "AirlineCode": "9E",
            "FlightNo": "777"
        },
        "return": {
            "SrNo": "xyz",
            "AirlineCode": "6G",
            "FlightNo": "546"
        }
    },
    "abc": {
        "onwards": {
            "SrNo": "abc",
            "AirlineCode": "5H",
            "FlightNo": "423"
        },
        "return": {
            "SrNo": "abc",
            "AirlineCode": "2G",
            "FlightNo": "420"
        }
    }
}
```

If you like, we can find a way to force keys to number.

```
$position = 0;
foreach ($newCollection as $itemKey => $itemValue) {
    $newCollection[++$position] = $itemValue;
    unset($newCollection[$itemKey]);
}

echo json_encode($newCollection, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

and this will output:

```
{
    "1": {
        "onwards": {
            "SrNo": "xyz",
            "AirlineCode": "9E",
            "FlightNo": "777"
        },
        "return": {
            "SrNo": "xyz",
            "AirlineCode": "6G",
            "FlightNo": "546"
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "onwards": {
            "SrNo": "abc",
            "AirlineCode": "5H",
            "FlightNo": "423"
        },
        "return": {
            "SrNo": "abc",
            "AirlineCode": "2G",
            "FlightNo": "420"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: like your suggestion. I'll try it.

Comment: Thank you very much ^_^.